# Product images issue in vue storefornt

Tags: magento2, vue-storefront

I integrated vue store front with magento 2, frontend works fine but product images not display in frontend. It throws error Unable to compile TypeScript:\nsrc/image/action/local/index.ts(27,18): error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request<any, any, any, any>'. imagemagick is also installed and imgurl in local.json is also defined.

Anyone please know about this why error display.

Comment: Try to include a snippet code, it will help you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

It is about `this.req` which is typeof `Request` from `express` - it has `query` property. Please make sure you have `yarn.lock` from the original repo and reinstall dependencies.

If you are using docker, you might need to add:
`- './yarn.lock/var/www/yarn.lock'`
To volumes section in the `docker-compose.nodejs.yml`

Answer (score 0):

i have found a simple solution you can try that

copy all your magento 2 pub/media data in vue-storefront-api/var/magento-folder/pub/media
Or
create a symlink if you are working on localhost

vue-storefront-api/config/local.json

> "magento2": {
> "imgUrl": "http://magento-domain/pub/media/catalog/product",
> "assetPath": "/../var/magento-folder/pub/media",
> }

vue-storefront/config/local.json

> "images": {
> "useExactUrlsNoProxy": false,
> "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/img/",
> "useSpecificImagePaths": false,
> "paths": {
> "product": "/catalog/product"
> },
> "productPlaceholder": "/assets/placeholder.jpg"
> },

run command in vue-storefront and vue-storefront-api